# wpf binding 2 properties of 2 classes

Tags: wpf, binding, properties

I have a XAML-object (window-control) having his own-properties in the code-behind (in my case it has a property called 'FirstEditableDate' without any UI-binding).

I also have another XAML-object (user-control) with a property (also without UI) and I want to bind the other property to this property.

So, if the property of the (main)class is changing, the other property of the usercontrol is also changing.

How can I do this?

(see for examples my 'answer' below...)

Comment: I don't understand nothing. Some code would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the Main class and have the usercontrol handle the PropertyChange event.

Comment: +1 Using INotifyPropertyChanged Or else, you can bind them like `this.SetBinding(FirstEditableDateProperty, new Binding(Source=this.userControlInstanceName, Path=new PropertyPath("PropertyInUserControl"), Mode=TwoWay));` Considering the property as DP.